# Botón HTML no hace href

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo un botón que quiero que haga un `href`, pero se me está haciendo imposible, ¿alguna idea de qué puede ser?

Este es el código:

**CSS** y **HTML**

```css
butn:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.butn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  -webkit-border-radius: 60;
  -moz-border-radius: 60;
  border-radius: 60px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #f586b3;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #f586b3 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.butn:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  text-decoration: none;
}

span.butn {
  margin-left: 24%;
}
```

```html
<a href="contacto.html"></a><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span>
```

Comment: No estas anidando bien las etiquetas, la etiqueta `<a>` debería envolver al `span`: `<a href="contacto.html"><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span></a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La etiqueta `a` cierra antes del span, por eso nunca se acciona el enlace

```
<a href="contacto.html"><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span></a>
```

```css
butn:hover { 
  background-color: yellow;
}

.butn {
  cursor:pointer;
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  -webkit-border-radius: 60;
  -moz-border-radius: 60;
  border-radius: 60px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #f586b3;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #f586b3 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.butn:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  text-decoration: none;
}

span.butn {
  margin-left: 24%;
}
```

```html
<a href="contacto.html"><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

No tienes el botón en el enlace.

```
<a href="contacto.html"></a><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span>
```

Estás cerrando el `a` antes del `span` y, por lo tanto, éste no está referenciado a ninguna parte. Es decir, por una parte tienes un enlace que redirige a `contacto.html` sin texto y, por lo tanto, no se ve en pantalla, y, por otra parte, tienes un `span` con apariencia de botón.

La forma de hacerlo sería:

```
<a href="contacto.html"><span class="butn">¡Me interesa!</span></a>
```

Debes meter el `span` dentro del `a` para que éste sirva de botón.